# Webstorm+TypeScript cannot resolve SCSS modules in CRA project (Error TS2339)

Tags: typescript, webstorm, create-react-app

I have a have a Create React App project that I'm currently migrating over from FlowJS to TypeScript. When I integrated TypeScript into the project, a problem that has arisen within WebStorm is that TypeScript cannot seem to resolve any keys from SCSS module imports. I always get greeted with the following:

[image: TS_SCSS_Error]

My top level styles import is: `import styles from './_styles.module.scss'`

After doing a lot of research/digging into trying to resolve this issue, I have a created a `src/global.d.ts` file that contains the following:

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: {
    [className: string]: string;
  }
  export = content
}
```

Despite having the above module defined, invalidating caches and restarting WebStorm, the problem still persists -- I no longer know what else to try in order to resolve this problem.

My TypeScript version is set to `"typescript": "^3.8.3"` within my `package.json`. And this is what my `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "plugins": [
      { "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }
    ],
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not very keen on the proposal that you declare your `src/` dir as a `typeRoot`. If you run `tsc --p tsconfig.json --listFiles`, is your global.d.ts listed?

Comment: @DavidBarker Yes, it's listed when I run that command.

Comment: Ok then it's not a typescript issue, likely specific to Webstorm. If you open up the typescript tab at the bottom, there is a button on the left (the top one) that will allow you recompile your project using a specific tsconfig.json. I would try that, if that doesn't work, I'd restart the typescript service.

Comment: how many `tsconfig.*.json` files do you have in your project? Is the file the issue is reported for included in any of them?

Comment: @lena I only have the one `tsconfig.json` file and my `src/global.d.ts` is included when I run the command @DavidBarker gave me in the above comment.

Comment: @DavidBarker I tried the Compile button on the TypeScript tab within WebStorm and the compile fails because the posted issue of keys not being found on the styles object. What throws me off is, even though TS doesn't compile, my app still runs fine with all the styles clearly applied in the browser. I restarted the TypeScript service and the issue still persists.

Comment: Question -- do I need to change my `"include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]` to simply be `"include": ["src/**/*"]`? Would that include the `scss` files into the compile process? Or is that already taken care of since my TS/TSX files include SCSS files?

Comment: I'm just looking back at a CRA project I did a while back that uses SASS. I didn't have this delcaration at all. I just had `node-sass` and `@types/node-sass`. Then just importing the SCSS file worked fine. Maybe try this method.

Comment: @DavidBarker when you say "I didn't have this delcaration at all" are you saying you didn't specify an `include` in your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: No, I didn't have any typescript module declaration for scss files. It wasn't needed.

Comment: similar code works fine for me in CRA project, the `d.ts` file is correctly recognized and no errors are shown. so it must be smth specific to your project setup

Comment: @DavidBarker I already had `node-sass` in my dependencies but adding `@types/node-sass` & restarting didn't solve the problem unfortunately...

Comment: @lena when you say `specific to your project setup`, are you referring to my current WebStorm preferences settings? Or whatever is in my `.idea` directory? Is there a way for me to "blow away" everything from WebStorm and have it create everything from scratch? Is it simply deleting my `.idea` folder?

Comment: no, it's not a problem with your IDE preferences(this behavior is not configurable), it must be something specific to the project structure and tsconfig.json(s) setup

Comment: @Danchez did you remove the `declare module '*.scss'` as well? That shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @DavidBarker I did but that did not work unfortunately. I'm all sorts of confused about why this problem is persisting the way that it is. I'm at my wits end and losing hope...but I really appreciate you assisting me throughout this.

Comment: @DavidBarker do you know if this plugin `typescript-plugin-css-modules` is necessary?

Comment: @DavidBarker Oh my gosh -- it's fixed!!! Turns out that the `typescript-plugin-css-modules` was the culprit in my problem! I went and removed it from my `tsconfig.json` and uninstalled the package and WebStorm is no longer complaining about my key references! I also didn't even have to install `@types/node-sass`. Oh man I'm so happy!!

Comment: @Danchez Thanks a ton for your inputs! It worked for me as well. But I wonder, how do my peers didn't get the error! We're working on the same repo since starting. This was something that came recently, and exclusively for me..!!

Comment: @Danchez Is webstorm showing you errors when accessing property that doesn't exist in CSS file?

Comment: @Danchez thanks a lot for the hint, I had the same issue! Removing the `typescript-plugin-css-modules` worked, and it did not break Webpack compiling. The issue is with the IDE not liking this package

Answer (score 0):

seems like typescript didn't pick up the definitions in `src/global.d.ts`, try to add src folder as a typing root folder in `tsconfig.json`, and restart typescript.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots" : ["src", "node_modules/@types"]
  }
}
```

more details: [@types, typeRoots and types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

Comment: Just added this, invalidated caches and restarted WebStorm -- it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Typescript is recognising your file, remove this, it's not needed.

Comment: Just note that the moment you set a `typeRoots` value in your `tsconfig` file, you override the defaults. While `node_modules/@types` is a good start, be sure your project doesn't have `../node_modules/@types` or `../../node_modules/@types`, and so on.